# Using HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to deal with exceptions in a WebAPI action method, by catching them setting the status code, and writing a message to the response. Normally in a normal MVC `Controller` I would do this like so, using `Controller`'s `Response` property:

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
Response.Write("Whatever");
```

However it seems `ApiController` doesn't have any `Response` property. Is there a reason for this? Is it OK to just use `HttpContext.Current.Response` like this:?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Whatever");
```

Or is there a specific way of writing to the response from a WebAPI controller??

Answer (score 7):

The action method is supposed to create the response object.  Either just do new HttpResponseMessage or call this.CreateResponse.

If instead of returning the HttpResponseMessage you want to return a custom CLR object then you will need to throw a HTTPResponseException to return a 404.

Comment: @dormisher  Just to add, try not to use HttpContext as it will prevent you from being able to use any other host other than IIS.

Comment: hey man - still having some trouble with this, when I throw a HttpResponseException, the response is simply an empty 200 - any idea why this is? I saw another SO answer saying to set this config val: <system.webServer><httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /></system.webServer> - but no change

Comment: @dormisher  Are you using Fiddler to look at the response?  You need to identify where the 404 status code is getting lost.  Fiddler will clarify if it is a server problem or a client problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a message that describes your exception, your best bet is to call [Request.CreateErrorResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127078%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), and use any of the many overloads available.  There are caveats to how the response is formatted depending on whether you have CustomErrors set to ON in your web.config, or whether you're in DEBUG mode.  You can actually configure this behavior programatically as well, using the HttpConfiguration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy property.  See here as well: http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2013/03/01/asp-net-web-api-logging-and-troubleshooting.aspx

You can read this article for an in depth write up, and some options you have to solve the exact problem you describe: [Web API, HttpError and the behavior of Exceptions – ‘An error has occurred’](http://blog.codeishard.net/2013/02/09/webapi-and-the-behavior-of-exceptions-and-an-alternative-configurable-way-to-deal/)